# split the string and process foreach-match it in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I've got bash variable

`USE_DOTNET="a b c"`

I need to go `foreach` `USE_DOTNET` and have some `case` (switch) for each pattern.

alike

```
foreach x in USE_DOTNET
switch(x)
case a -> do something
case b -> ...
```

in pseudo code but I don't know how to implement it in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

USE_DOTNET="a b c"

for x in ${USE_DOTNET} ; do
   case ${x} in 
      a) echo "found x="$x ;;
      b) echo "found b"
      c) echo "FOUND c"
      * ) echo "unexpected value found for x=$x" 1>&2
   esac
done
```

OR, per @jordanm's comment, you can try

```
USE_DOTNET=(a b c)
for x in "${USE_DOTNET[@]}" ;do ...
```

IHTH

(FWIW, your pcode looks close to csh syntax)

Comment: @jordanm, perfectly valid to take advantage of the shell's word splitting as per the first example.